# How to detect for player with custom head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on an adventure map with quests etc, and need to testfor a player with a certain item in their inventory.
The item in question is a custom head with a few attributes–here's the /give command I used for it:

```
/give @p skull 1 3 {LeafyHeaddress:1b,display:{Name:"Leafy Headdress",Lore:["[Rare] [Quest Item]","Some irritating thorns poke out of it."]},SkullOwner:{Id:"8dc9da4f-e33d-2a9b-fd5f-39628f3c4bb4",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNDNkYjgxNDRhMjNjYzU4NTkzMTU2M2VkNDMzMGE5ODYyYjhkNzk4ZWE0YjE1ZTNlMzE4YWM2NDk0Mzg0MSJ9fX0="}]}},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:0.15,Operation:1,UUIDMost:10481,UUIDLeast:32056}],ench:[{id:7,lvl:1}]}
```

I saw [in another post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278986/how-do-you-test-if-a-player-is-holding-a-skull-with-a-skull-owner) that I could detect it with a custom tag, which I tried to use above ^ (LeafyHeaddress)

The command I'm using to test for it is:
`/testfor @a {Inventory:[{tag:{LeafyHeaddress:1b}}]}`
Problem is, the command block outputs nothing when a player has the item. The error simply says that the player in question did not "match the required data structure" (which I take to mean it didn't detect the item)

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: Though I do not use commands, I have read up on it and it seems the leafy headdress's id isn't correct. All minecraft id's are defined with a "minecraft." tag (like "minecraft.bed") in recent updates (like 1.7 or 1.8?) Maybe it would be worth trying to get the exact id internal of the headdress instead of using it's name.

Comment: The ID for it is minecraft:skull, i just gave it a special tag, and should be able to identify it with said tag.

Answer (score 1):

Create scoreboard `wSkull`: `scoreboard objectives add wSkull dummy`

[1]Repeating command block: `scoreboard players set @a wSkull 1 {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:skull",tag:{display:{Name:"Leafy Headdress",Lore:["[Rare] [Quest Item]","Some irritating thorns poke out of it."]}}}]}`

[2]Repeating command block: `execute @a[score_wSkull_min=1] ~ ~ ~ [command you want to happen when the custom head was worn]`

At `[2]Repeating command block`, you can do multiple of these if you want alot of things to happen whoever wears your head.

`Slot:103b` locates where the helmet should be put when you want to wear it inside your inventory.

Answer (score -1):

the 1b part isn't necessary.
 Instead do the following: `/give @p minecraft:skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"[LeafyHeaddress]"}`

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What does each part of the command do?